# contextual action bar - getting rid of Select Action text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I've implemented a contextual action bar. The menu being loaded and inflated in onCreateActionMode is defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:title="@string/call_context_menu_title">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_answer_call"
    android:title="@string/answerCall"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<group android:id="@+id/activeCallContextMenuItems">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_end_call"
      android:title="@string/hangupCall"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<group android:id="@+id/multipleActiveCallsContextMenuItems">
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_transfer_call"
        android:title="@string/transferCall"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_conference_call"
        android:title="@string/conferenceCall"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</group>
</group>
</menu>
```

These items are shown when I click on an item in a ListView. When it is active, besides listing my 4 options, it puts a "Select Action" text before the first menu item. Is there any way to get Android to not show the "Select Action" hint? The menu items have self explanatory text so it is redundant (and even confusing if the hint is being cut off in the middle... e.g. on my S3 it says "Select..." and then I have my menu items)

Comment: Have you tried getActionBar().setTitle(""); ? Maybe I misunderstood what you were trying to accomplish but this worked for me :)

Comment: Urgh - sometimes it's the most simple things (and I need to figure out how to get response notification in this place).

Comment: Followup: Can I use the space that I just freed up for other items? If I set an empty title, I just get a lot of unused space.